# SQL query result to variable?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I usually do this in VB and its much easier, this is my first time in C# and I can't figure it out.  I'm just wanting to read a row, check that it has rows, and assign the number that exist in that column to `StockQuan`

```
    public int StockQuan;
    public int NewAmount;

    public const string ConnectionStringToORACLE = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=Souarce;User ID=user;Password=pass;";
    public OleDbDataReader rowread;

    public OleDbDataReader Read_quan(string txtPartNo, int txtAmount)
    {
        var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE);
        conn.Open();

        string query = "select QUANTITY_IN_STOCK from MPCS.SHOP_INV_STOCK where SI_KEY = ? AND LOCATION = ?";
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SI_KEY", txtPartNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LOCATION", "HQ-TC");

        //rowread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //rowread.Read();
        //if (rowread.HasRows)
        //{
            //while (rowread.Read())
            //{
                StockQuan = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            //}
            NewAmount = StockQuan - txtAmount;

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Error reading quantity. Check with Administrator", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        //}
        return rowread;
    }
```

I commented out most things to just simplify where I'm going wrong and now the error is invalid cast on `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: What happens if you run the above code and there is no matching record (i.e. it returns 0 rows)?

Comment: _The way you are executing SQL does work, but you may consider using a lightweight ORM like https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper . It may make your life a little easier._

Comment: What's the type of QUANTITY_IN_STOCK  in DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
 StockQuan = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: @Boneist I was but when doing so I was told I had to wait 10 minutes before marking it as the correct answer.